# Problemas con guardar objetos en el environment en R

Tags: r, rstudio

Creo una función que permite juntar data frames usando `rbind()`

La función es la siguiente **(lo pueden correr ya que se genera con datos aleatorios)**

```
juntador<-function(x){
  for (i in 1:x) {
    assign(paste0("data_",i), data.frame(var1=sample(1:10), var2=sample(1:10)))
  }
  lista<-lapply(ls(pattern = "^data"), get)
  junte<-do.call(rbind, lista)
  return(junte)
}
```

Entonces, la función toma como argumento un número, y en función a este, se crea data frames, para luego unirlos.

Por ejemplo, si considero 3. Debería de juntar los 3 dataframes que acabo de crear.

```
juntador(3)

# NULL
```

Pero me arroja `NULL`, esto presumo se debe a que en la ejecución del `lapply` no se guardó en el environment. Por lo que coloco esto en cada una de las líneas.

```
juntador<-function(x){
  for (i in 1:x) {
    assign(paste0("data_",i), data.frame(var1=sample(1:10), var2=sample(1:10)), 
           envir = globalenv())
  }
  lista<-lapply(ls(pattern = "^data"), function(x){get(x, envir = globalenv())})
  junte<-do.call(rbind, lista, envir = globalenv())
  return(junte)
}
```

Pero ni así logro obtener lo deseado. Me sigue arrojando `NULL`.

¿A qué se debe? ¿Dónde tengo que corregir?

Comment: as intentado move el ` lista<-lapply(ls(pattern = "^data"), get)` dentro del scope de  tu for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Efectivamente es un tema de entornos: hay dos importantes a tener en cuenta cuando trabajamos con funciones, por que son los que determinan el orden en que se buscan los símbolos (por ejemplo las variables):

1. el "Calling environment", que es desde el cual se invoca la función.
2. el "Enclosing environment", que es aquel dónde se define la función.

Siempre se comienza a buscar la variable en el entorno en que se está invocando la función y si no se encuentra en este se va al entorno dónde se ha definido la función.

Cuando invocas `get()` en forma directa, el "Calling environment" es el de tu función, dónde tienes definidas las variables y obviamente `get()` no tiene problema en encontrarlas, ahora cuando invocas mediante `lapply()` el "Calling environment" es el de `lapply()` (es dentro de `lapply` dónde se invoca `get()`) y en este environment no tienes definida la variable a buscar, por lo que al no encontrar la variable, se la va a buscar al "enclosing environment" que en el caso de `get()` es el entorno global, dónde no la tienes definida, de hecho, a modo de demostración, si la defines afuera de tu función, seguramente no tengas el error, aunque claro no es lo que estás buscando:

```
data_1 <- data.frame(var1=sample(1:10), var2=sample(1:10)
juntador(1)
```

Aquí hemos creado un objeto `data_1` en el mismo entorno dónde esta definido `get()` al fallar la búsqueda en el `calling environment` se buca el símbolo en el espacio global.

En el caso de `get()` lo que si podrías hacer, por que la función lo implementa, es indicarle en que entorno quieres que busque `lista<-lapply(ls(pattern = "^data"), get, env = environment())`, el tercer parámetro se pasa directo a `get` y básicamente le estamos diciendo que busque las variables en un entorno específico, en este caso el entorno correspondiente al de tu función

```
juntador<-function(x){
  for (i in 1:x) {
    assign(paste0("data_",i), data.frame(var1=sample(1:10), var2=sample(1:10)))
  }
  lista<-lapply(ls(pattern = "^data"), get, env = environment())
  junte<-do.call(rbind, lista)
  return(junte)
}
```

Para mayor información recomiendo **Advance R** de Hadley Wickham y el capitulo: [Environments](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html)

Comment: Wao... Muchas gracias. Ahora sí me quedó claro. Sí, ahora corrijo el for, tenían el problema en un caso que lo estaba viendo y trate de ponerlo en un caso muy sencillo, ahí se me pasó el length(). Nuevamente, muchas gracias.